# Were James Smyth Stacy and family in London, Devon or elsewhere for 1841 Census?

Tags: 19th-century, devon, census-records, london

My 3rd great grandparents James Smyth Stacy and Elizabeth Mary Murch arrived at Port Adelaide, South Australia, on 12 Oct 1849, along with their five children that included my 2nd great grandfather John Murch Stacy.

This timing means that the only England Census return that they should have made was in 1841 but I cannot find it.

James was a Boot and Shoe Maker but he was one of six brothers all making their way in life after their father John Stacy's lead with business interests in Devon and London.

To get some ideas where they might have been living in 1841 I have looked at the parents and children's births:

- James Smyth Stacy born 30 Dec 1804 at Exmouth, Devon
- Elizabeth Mary Murch born 13 Dec 1791 at Totnes, Devon
- James Murch Stacy born 16 Oct 1827 at London (baptised Finsbury Circus)
- John Murch Stacy born 14 Jun 1830 at Plymouth, Devon
- William Henry Stacy born 5 Oct 1831 at Totnes, Devon
- Sarah Jane Stacy born 14 Jun 1833 at London
- Harriet Sophia Stacy born 31 Dec 1837 at Totnes, Devon

From 1842 their whereabouts are more clear because James Smyth Stacy appears in Electoral Registers and Directories:

- 1842 - Tower Hamlets, Shoreditch, England
- 1843 - 184 Kingsland road, London
- 1845 - 174 Kingsland road, Tower Hamlets, St Leonard Shoreditch
- 1846 - 184 Kingsland road, Tower Hamlets, St Leonard Shoreditch
- 1848 - 184 Kingsland road

After many census searches via Ancestry and FindMyPast around London and Devon, I am now after new ideas on where I may be able to search?  In particular, if anyone knows how I could determine the particular 1841 Census Page to look for 184 Kingsland road, Tower Hamlets, St Leonard Shoreditch I think that would be a good next step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the [1841 census search page](http://search.findmypast.co.uk/search-world-records/1841-england-wales-and-scotland-census) at FindMyPast and put "Kingsland Road" in the "Street" field which is the very last field then you will find yourself with a page full of results for Kingsland Road in St Leonard, Shoreditch which I think is the one you want.

Further investigation finds a [family that appears to match](http://search.findmypast.co.uk/record?id=gbc%2F1841%2F0007778820&highlights=%22%22) at:

```
Archive reference: HO107
Piece number: 709
Book number: 2
Folio number: 7
Page number: 7
```

That has an entry at the bottom of the left hand page for James (35, Shoe M.), Elizabeth (45), James (12), John (10), William (9), Sarah (8) and Harriett (3).

Comment: Thanks so much for that!  It is indeed them and that address search on FindMyPast is something that I am sure I can find some more use for.